# Commutant of the conjugations by unitary matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

Let $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^{n \times n})$ denote the algebra of all linear mappings from $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ to $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and let $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^{n \times n})$ denote the subalgebra of all $\phi \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^{n \times n})$ which satisfy
$$
\phi(U^*AU) = U^*\phi(A)U
$$
for all $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and all unitary $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ (in other words, $\mathcal{C}$ is the commutant of the set of all conjugations by unitary matrices).

**Question.** Is there an explicit description of $\mathcal{C}$?

Of course, there is some freedom for interpretation of the word "explicit"; I would be most happy with a set of mappings in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^{n \times n})$ which spans $\mathcal{C}$.

**Remarks:**

- Clearly, the identity $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}$ is an element of $\mathcal{C}$.
- The operator $\tau: \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}\to \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ given by 
  $$
  \tau(A) = \operatorname{tr}(A) \cdot \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}
  $$
  is an element of $\mathcal{C}$ (where $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ denotes the trace of the matrix $A$).
- The span of $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}} $ and $\tau$ is a subalgebra of $\mathcal{C}$ (since $\tau^2 = n\tau$), but I don't know whether $\mathcal{C}$ is larger than this span.

Comment: The conjugation representation of $\mathrm U(n)$ on $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)$ decomposes into irreducible representations, and the algebra of $\mathrm U(n)$-equivariant maps is completely determined by this decomposition: it is a sum of matrix algebras, one for each irreducible component, of the size equal to the multiplicity of that irreducible component. Now, there is, for instance, $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ as an irreducible subspace (and $\mathbb C\cdot 1$, as well). I don't know the decomposition of $\mathfrak{su}(n)^\perp$ off the top of my head, but it should be in the literature.

Comment: I just realised that $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is a real, not complex, subrep'n. Its complex counterpart is $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$, and it's irreducible (see answer below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building up on my comment, I can now give the complete answer. The space of matrices can be decomposed as follows:
$$
\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C) = \mathbb C\cdot\mathrm{id}\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(n),
$$
where
$$
\mathfrak{sl}(n) = \{X\in\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)\mid \mathrm{Tr}(X) = 0\}.
$$

Thus, the conjugation representation of $\mathrm{U}(n)$ decomposes as the sum of a trivial representation and the conjugation repesentation on $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$. The latter is irreducible as a complex representation of $\mathrm{U}(n)$ because:

- the complexification of $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ is $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$, and
- the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ is a simple complex Lie algebra.

Therefore the algebra of linear $\mathrm U(n)$-equivariant maps is isomorphic to $\mathbb C\oplus \mathbb C$. The elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are just orthogonal projections to $\mathbb C\cdot \mathrm{id}$ and its orthogonal complement $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$.

So, the space $\mathcal C$ from the question is indeed spanned by $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb M_n}$ and $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you specify what you mean by $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ (as opposed to $U(n)$)?

Comment: The Lie algebra of $\mathrm{U}(n)$: $\mathfrak u(n) = \{X\in\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)\mid X^* = -X\}$.

Answer (score 5):

$\mathcal{C}$ is simply the span of the two maps that you noted (the identity and the trace) -- there is nothing else in the commutant.

One (admittedly somewhat roundabout) way of seeing this is to notice that if you unpack $\phi$ into an $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix $\Phi$ in the "usual" way (i.e., instead of thinking of it as a linear transformation acting on matrices, think of it as a matrix acting on their [vectorizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization)), then your commutation relation is equivalent to
$$
(U \otimes \overline{U})\Phi(U \otimes \overline{U})^* = \Phi
$$
for all unitary $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ (here $\overline{U}$ is the entrywise complex conjugate of $U$).

This is the defining property of something called an [isotropic state](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/isotropic-state) from quantum information theory, and it is well-known (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9708015), for example) that all matrices with this property are linear combinations of the identity matrix and the "maximally entangled state" $\rho = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \mathbf{e}_i\mathbf{e}_j^* \otimes \mathbf{e}_i\mathbf{e}_j^*$ (where $\{\mathbf{e}_i\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$). These two matrices correspond to the trace linear map and the identity linear map, respectively, once you "un-vectorize" everything.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! After I while of thinking I finally chose to accept Vadim Alekseev' answer (although your post answers my question as well) since he was a bit earlier and since his answer "forced" me to learn a few facts about Lie algebras ;-). Anyway, I'm very grateful to you for pointing out the connection to quantum information theory!

Answer (score 0):

I posted (nearly) this on MSE, so if it doen't belong here plese remove.

Let $\Phi\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^{n \times n})$ and suppose that for any unitary
conjugation operator $\mathcal{U}\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^{n \times n})$,
$\mathcal{U}\Phi=\Phi\mathcal{U}$. Let $\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$ denote the standard
orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$, let $e_{ij}$ denote the $n\times n$ matrix with $1$ in the $i$th row
$j$th column and zeros elswhere, and let $E_{ij}=\Phi(e_{ij})$. Claim,
there exists $r,s\in\mathbb{C}$ such that,
\begin{equation}
  E_{ij}=\begin{cases} re_{ij} & \text{ if } i\neq j, \text{ and }\\
    %
    re_{ij}+sI & \text{ if } i= j,
  \end{cases}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
so that for $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$,
$\Phi(B)=rB+\mathrm{tr}(B)sI$. Accordingly, fix $1\leq i,j\leq n$ with
$i\neq j$, let $K_{ij}$ denote the span of $\{e_i,e_j\}$, and let
$P_{ij}$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $K_{ij}$. Notate the
compressions to $K_{ij}$ by
\begin{gather*}\epsilon_{ii}=P_{ij}E_{ii}\Bigm|_{K_{ij}}=
  \begin{bmatrix} a_{ii} & b_{ii} \\
    c_{ii} & d_{ii}  \end{bmatrix}\qquad
  %
  \epsilon_{ij}=P_{ij}E_{ij}\Bigm|_{K_{ij}}=
  \begin{bmatrix} a_{ij} & b_{ij} \\
    c_{ij} & d_{ij}  \end{bmatrix}\\
  %
  \epsilon_{ji}=P_{ij}E_{ji}\Bigm|_{K_{ij}}=
  \begin{bmatrix} a_{ji} & b_{ji} \\
    c_{ji} & d_{ji}  \end{bmatrix}\qquad
  %
  \epsilon_{jj}=P_{ij}E_{jj}\Bigm|_{K_{ij}}=
  \begin{bmatrix} a_{jj} & b_{jj} \\
    c_{jj} & d_{jj}  \end{bmatrix}
  %
\end{gather*}

Let $U_{1}$, $U_{2}$, and $U_{3}$ be the unitary matrices which fix
the orthogonal complement of $K_{ij}$ with action on $K_{ij}$ given by
$u_{1}=\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$,
$u_{2}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and
$u_{3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
  -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ respectively. Note that for
$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c &
  d\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C},$

$$u_1Au_1^\dagger=\begin{bmatrix} a & -ib \\ ic &  d\end{bmatrix}\quad
u_2Au_2^\dagger=\begin{bmatrix} d & c \\ b &  a\end{bmatrix}\quad
u_3Au_3^\dagger= \frac12\begin{bmatrix}
 a+b+c+d & -a+b-c+d \\ -a-b+c+d &  a-b-c+d \end{bmatrix}$$

For $k=1,2,3$, $U_kP_{ij}=P_{ij}U_k$ so that
$\mathcal{U}_{k}\Phi= \Phi\mathcal{U}_{k}$ implies for
$\ell,m\in\{i,j\}$ ,
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:compression}
  u_k\epsilon_{\ell m}u_k^\dagger=
P_{ij}\Phi(U_ke_{\ell m}U_k^\dagger)\Bigm|_{K_{ij}}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
With $k=1$, equation (2) shows that the off-diagonal entries of
$\epsilon_{ii}$ and $\epsilon_{jj}$ equal zero and that all entries of
$\epsilon_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_{ji}$ except for $b_{ij}$ and $c_{ji}$
must equal zero. Since $\mathcal{U}_2(e_{ii})=e_{jj}$, $a_{ii}=d_{jj}$
and $d_{ii}=a_{jj}$, and since $\mathcal{U}_2(e_{ij})=e_{ji}$,
$b_{ij}=c_{ji}$. With these identities, it follows that
$2u_3\epsilon_{ij}u_3^\dagger=
\begin{bmatrix}b_{ij} & b_{ij} \\ -b_{ij} &
  -b_{ij} \end{bmatrix}$. Further, since
$2U_3e_{ij}U_3^\dagger=e_{ii}+e_{ij}-e_{ii}-e_{ii}$,
$$\begin{bmatrix}b_{ij} & b_{ij} \\ -b_{ij} &
  -b_{ij} \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} a_{ii}-d_{ii} & b_{ij} \\
  -b_{ij} & d_{ii}-a_{ii}\end{bmatrix},$$
so that $a_{ii}-d_{ii} = b_{ij}$. Letting $r=b_{ij}$ and  $s=d_{ii}$ one has,
$$\epsilon_{ii}=\begin{bmatrix} s+r & 0 \\
    0 & s  \end{bmatrix}\quad
  %
\epsilon_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & r \\
    0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\qquad
  %
\epsilon_{ji}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\
    r & 0  \end{bmatrix}\qquad
  %
\epsilon_{jj}=\begin{bmatrix} s & 0\\
    0 & s+r  \end{bmatrix}\qquad
  %
$$
Letting $i,j$ run through all unequal pairs yields equation (1).

Remark. Using similar techniques one can show the following.
Let $\Phi\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^{n\times n})$ and suppose that for any
orthogonal conjugation operator
$\mathcal{O}\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^{n\times n})$,
$\mathcal{O}\Phi=\Phi\mathcal{O}$. There exists $r,s,t\in\mathbb{C}$
such that, for $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$,
$\Phi(B)=rB+sB^\top+\mathrm{tr}(B)tI$.